# Ubuntu is installed, but not showing up on grub menu

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS onto my computer. I installed it on my whole disk, removing Windows. Installation completed and when I restarted my computer, I was not given the option to boot into Ubuntu. I was presented with these options:

```
Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Check disc for defects
```

The basic option for "Ubuntu" is not showing up. However, if I click on "Install Ubuntu", the installer recognizes that Ubuntu 16.04 is already installed on my computer, and asks if I wish to dual boot along side it, or delete it and re-install.

So my computer has Ubuntu 16.04 installed, I'm just unable to boot into it from Grub menu.

Comment: Try to remove the live image (CD/USB - whatever you used) and then start your computer. If it is inserted, the computer loads it instead of the actual OS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed all installation media, this has happened once or twice when the both the cd drive and the flash storage are still attached.

If you keep getting this interface after removing all media then you may have botched your install, just try it again and make a record of every choice you make while installing this way you know exactly what you've done and have some easy to retrieve info when posting  installations issues.

To address your problem, try removing install media from your machine. If it persists boot into the live environment and post a screen grab of your current hard drive layout (just type disk into unity dash).

We'll take from there.